# Why doesn't work css style customization for react-component

Tags: css, reactjs

I created react-component, which gets title and color and must to render component with name of color and color example. Code is here

```
  import React from "react";

const Color = ({ color, title }) => {
  console.log(color);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{title}</p>
      <div className="color" style={{ backgroundColor: color }} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Color;
```

But render only title, but background color doesn't changes.

p.s. **This is React, so backgroundColor is correct version of attribute**

Comment: `style={{backgroundColor:"red"}}` instead

Comment: `backgroundColor="red"` is not valid, you need to have `style="background-color: red"`

Comment: Is there anything inside the `<div>` with a background colour, or does it have dimensions of zero so you don't see it? Have you inspected the rendered HTML with the developer tools in a browser (press F12)?

Comment: @AndrewMorton thank you, you are correct, please render your comment as answer, I will check it such as correct. Root cause is 0 height

Answer (score 0):

If there nothing inside the `<div>` with a background colour then it will have dimensions of zero so you won't see it. (As long as there is no other styling which we can't see here that gives it a size.)

You can inspect the rendered HTML with the developer tools in a browser (press F12) to confirm that.